# Parsing data to Javascript array with D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have an issue I can't wrap my head around. I have a CSV file with the following columns:

**Name Info1 Info2 Value1 Value2 Value3 Value3**

From this, using `d3.csv`, I am trying to create a javascript array that looks like this, for each row in of the data:

```
[{key: Name,
    Info1: Info1,
    Info2: Info2,
    values: [{
        Value1: Value1,
        Value2: Value2,
        Value3: Value3
    }]
}]
```

Can't really wrap my head around how to do this. Anyone?

Edit: Problem solved. Now, how can I operate on the sub-array of values, for example for each key separately extract the mean?

Edit 2: Never mind, solved that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do it (*change the filename to what you need*)

```
d3.csv("dataset.csv", function(data) {
  dataset = data.map(function(d) {
    return {
      key: d.Name,
      Info1: d.Info1,
      Info2: d.Info2,
      values: [{
        Value1: d.Value1,
        Value2: d.Value2,
        Value3: d.Value3
      }]
    };
  });

  return dataset;
});
```

Demo at http://plnkr.co/edit/aVfrCC?p=preview

Comment: So straightforward I should really have been able to figure it out myself. Thanks!